# How can you use a variable to change label options

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
form = "root, text='Hello'"
Label(form).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This is a basic example, but the premise stays the same. The above code outputs an error whereas the code below works. Is there some way to fix the code at the top to work like the one at the bottom?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
Label(root, text='Hello').pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you explain yourself a bit better? In any case Python would not evaluate your string into code unless you explicitly do that with `eval()` which I would not use lightheartedly.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Why do you want to have that particular bit of code stored in a string variable? It sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): "The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem. That is, you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y."

Comment: let me rephrase my comment: would you expect `a = "print(10)"; a` work the same as `print(10)`? why?

Comment: Please read the following documentation, then edit and rephrase the question.  [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I want to use the variable as the code to change the details of the label.

Comment: 'do that with eval()'.Thanks norok2

Comment: Actually eval() only works when the whole string is acceptable code, when the code is additional, it doesn't work.

Comment: VijayS. Do not use eval. It is almost never needed and is not the safest bit of code out there. You can do everything you need to with a label by using `config()` or `StringVar`.

Answer (score 2):

To python `form = "root, text='Hello'"` is literally just a string variable with the value of `"root, text='Hello'"`. When you try to use this in a function/method it is treated as a sting and if that function/method was not designed to do something with that string object then it will error. A tkinter widget typically takes its first value as the container object. The following arguments are comma separated and are typically all keyword arguments. The Button method has no way of knowing you want it to convert that string into a keyword argument or a positional argument. You have to do it the way it was designed to be used.

What you can do is pass a variable that contains a string or some other value like an integer/float as the keyword argument `text` is read in a way that can read things like strings, int, boolean and so on.

Something like this is fine:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

text_var = 'Hello'
tk.Label(root, text=text_var).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you want to be able to both use a starting variable value and something that can be updated down the road you can use a `StringVar()` to update you label text by using the `textvariable` argument.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

label_var = tk.StringVar()
label_var.set('Testing')


def update_label():
    label_var.set('Updated Label')


tk.Label(root, textvariable=label_var).pack()
tk.Button(root, text='Update Label', command=update_label).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You can also simply update the label in a function with the `config` method.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()


def update_label():
    label.config(text='Updated Label')


label = tk.Label(root, text='Testing')
label.pack()
tk.Button(root, text='Update Label', command=update_label).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to store the `root, text=` part in a variable. To have the label text vary store the text and only the text in a variable like so:

```
message = "Hello"
Label(root, text=message).pack()
```

This way you can vary the part that varies while leaving `root` and `text` as fixed identifiers. Identifiers are supposed to be written out directly in source code. You don't store variable names in variables.